# Jommla connect to another database using Multisites extension

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using Joomla 2.5 and Multisites extensions. When I'm on page X Joomla is using X-database, on page Y using Y-database - it's ok. Unfortunately I have to switch to another database.  How I said `$db = JFactory::getDbo();` connect to current site database, because Multisites extension works that every page has his own configuration file with database parameters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
$option['driver'] = 'mysqli';
$option['host'] = 'localhost';
$option['user'] = 'root';
$option['password'] = '';
$option['database'] = 'joomla';
$option['prefix'] = 'a45gy_';
JFactory::destroy();
$db = JDatabase::getInstance($option);
if (JError::isError($db)) {
    jexit('Database Error: ' . $db->toString());
}

if ($db->getErrorNum() > 0) {
    JError::raiseError(500, 'JDatabase::getInstance: Could not connect to database <br />');
}
parent::setDbo($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

### try it.

```
$dbX = JDatabase::getInstance(array ('host' => $host, 'user' => $user, 'password' => $pass, 'database' => $database, 'prefix'=>null));

$dbY = JDatabase::getInstance(array ('host' => $host, 'user' => $user, 'password' => $pass, 'database' => $database, 'prefix'=>null));
```

Comment: When I use `$dbX = JFactory::getDbo($host,$user,$pass,$database,$prefix=null,$select=true);` in model database connect to site-database

Comment: changed code. i had a mistake. i tried and this worked.